# logstash : exclude bots from result

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, bots

I use logstash to store my web server logs into an elasticsearch engine. Into my logstash configuration file I also use the "useragent" plugin to get pretty user agent informations. So a record into ES like this :

```
    "message": "157.55.XXX.XXX - - [10/Oct/2016:02:24:27 +0200] "GET /handle/boreal:5621?site_name=BOREAL HTTP/1.1" 301 373 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"",
    ...
    "agent": ""Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)""
    "useragent": {
        "name": "bingbot",
        "os": "Other",
        "os_name": "Other",
        "device": "Spider",
        "major": "2",
        "minor": "0"
    }
```

As you notices, this request is from the Microsoft BingBot robot. I checked all my record and I find a lot of bot accessing my websites : bingbot, googlebot, BaiduSpider, Yahoo! Slurp, ...

I'm now tring to exclude these requests from my ES response. But I didn't find an elegant solution. As I'm very beginner with ES query, can you help me to improve my request ?

```
{                                               
  "size": 0,                                    
  "query": {                                    
    "filtered": {                               
      "query": {                                
        "match_all": {}                         
      },                                        
      "filter": {                               
        "bool": {                               
          "must_not": [                         
            {                                   
              "regexp": {                       
                "useragent.name": ".*bot.*"     
              }                                 
            }                                   
          ]                                     
        }                                       
      }                                         
    }                                           
  },                                            
  "aggs": {                                     
    "agent": {                                  
      "terms": {                                
        "field": "useragent.name.raw"           
      }                                         
    }                                           
  }                                             
}
```

Using this request, all request from bingbot, googlebot, or any other "stuffbot" are exclude but not "Yahoo! Slurp","BaiduSpider", ...
I tried with more complex regexp "(.*bot.*|BaiduSpider|Yahoo! Slurp)" but Baidu and yahoo results are still present into ES response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already using the [useragent logstash filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-useragent.html), you can benefit from the excellent and apparently well maintained [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-core/blob/master/regexes.yaml). It recognizes a lot of bots and marks them as "useragent.device:Spider".
A suitable query for elasticsearch could be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": { "useragent.device": "Spider" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might, however, need to update the filter plugin on a regular basis, for example using:

```
logstash-plugin update logstash-filter-useragent
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using multiple objects inside `must_not`, which is an array. One for each bot to exclude from results.

From documentation:

> must_not: All of these clauses must not match. The equivalent of NOT.

Something like this:

```
"filter": {                               
  "bool": {                               
    "must_not": [
      {
        "regexp": { "useragent.name": "regex for bing bot" }                                 
      },
      {
        "regexp": { "useragent.name": "regex for google bot" }                                 
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

If user agent is static you can avoid `regexp` altogether with `term`:

```
{
  "term" : { "useragent.name": "bing bot agent name" } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the necessary regexps, you could put them into logstash and have it tag the event.  This would make your queries shorter, easier to read, and faster.

Comment: Using this solution if a new bot appears, I need to update the logstash config and reparse the file. It's why I would prefer an ElasticSearch solution.

Comment: With a query, you'd still have to realize the existence of the new bot, update your queries, and republish and data/reports that were based on the old queries.  With logstash, you would not need to reload the entire file with logstash, but could do an update by query or use logstash to query elasticsearch and tag any documents with the new agent.  Your queries would be much cleaner, and you'd have one place to maintain the list of agents.  There are tradeoffs everywhere.